# How to prorate a Stripe subscription before cancellation

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I would like to know how to prorate the unused amount of a Stripe subscription when cancelling the subscription immediately. While I went through the Stripe docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/cancel), the Java example doesn't specify how to pass proration params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
Subscription subscription =
  Subscription.retrieve(
    "sub_xxx"
  );

params.put("prorate", true);

Subscription deletedSubscription =
  subscription.cancel(params);
```